# in app purchase testing is done, do I need to do anything before uploading to app store

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have made an app and integrated in app purchases feature.
After reading a lot and lot I have finally working in app purchasing featured app and when I use my test account (created through iTunesconnect), it all just go smoothly and works as like expected.

I just wanted to ask that, do I need to make any configuration in iTunes connect or enable/disable any options before going live by uploading the app to the app store?

Or should I consider that if the test account works well, it will be working live too without any additional changes.

Also let me tell you all that I am a beginner for this in-app purchasing concern so please forgive if this is a silly question. :)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you link the in-app purchase to the correct version of your app in iTunes Connect and that your in-app purchase is ready for review. It that is correct, then you're ready for upload and review.